# Maven to use same API document for all projects(mvn site customised)

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have one Maven project , there i have a created a site with all css and images i added manually , then i want to reuse that API where  ever it called.

In another project if i execute this command mvn site.. it will generate site with API documents but i want to apply the above css and images which is in another project by default when ever i enter mvn site or deploying..

i tried dependency but not working.
And i dont want to use skins..How to do? ..Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you like to use skins? This the way in Maven to create customized page layouts...what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply !  But there is no site.xml in the parent project .And the requirement is like if i add dependency it should add the css and images automatically ingenerated API in the parent project using MVN site command..

Comment: Than you have to go via Maven Skin. Your parent project needs to define once the customized skin and any other project can inherit from.

Comment: yes and i can do that, then how to generate site.xml in the existing project.  Even i added dependency it is not adding site.xml

Comment: even in one project i configured site.xml and adding that dependecy in another project , still it is not working .. still its coming default site

Comment: If you have different css etc. you need to go via skin.

Comment: I have a such a requirement, pls let me know, is there any possibily if i add dependency , is it able to add images and css in that project - target - in site folder directly .

Comment: Take a deeper look here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creatingskins.html

Answer (score 1):

Skins
The following table lists skins that are available for you to use in your Maven generated site.

Skin    Version Description

- Maven Application Skin   1.0 -A skin used by applications like
  Continuum.
- Maven Classic Skin 1.1   -This skin resembles the look of a    site
  generated by Maven 1.
- Maven Default Skin   1.1 You get this skin    if you don't specify any
  skin.
- Maven Stylus Skin    1.5 The skin used    for the website of Maven
  itself. Maven Fluido Skin    1.4 Skin based on    bootstrap CSS.

To use one of these skins in your project, you use the skin element of the site descriptor. This is a regular artifact or dependency-like element. For example, to use the Maven Classic Skin, you would include the this in your site.xml file:

```
<project>
  ...
   <skin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-classic-skin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </skin>
  ...
</project>
```

Skins reference documentations are archived [here](http://maven.apache.org/skins-archives/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply !  But there is no site.xml in the parent project .And the requirement is like if i add dependency it should add the css and images automatically ingenerated API in the parent project using MVN site command..

Comment: I have a such a requirement, pls let me know is there any possibily if i add dependency , is it able to  add images and css in that project  in target and in site folder .